# How to increment the date's year by 1 in using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

If I have a date `15/11/2001` stored in database, I want to increate the year of the date by `1` to be `15/11/2002` .. ?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean 2002...

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx). For example, in a query:

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, 1, [myDate])
FROM [myTable]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) :

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, 1, '2001-11-15');
```